# Newbie in SAS: Is there a way to create variable (integer) in Proc sql and call it throughout the script?

Tags: sas, proc

I am proficient in SQl, Excel and Python but SAS is new to me.
Question: Can you create a variable integer as (Python: x=01Jul2020 or y=4) and call it throughout the document? I want to create a script that has in multiple Proc SQL statement a date (say 01Jul2020).
In case I want to look at different points in time (change from 01JUl2020 to 01Aug2020) I only have to change the variable in the beginning of the script and not everywhere I use this date? And how do I call this variable in the document within a Proc SQL statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `MACRO` symbols (commonly known as macro variables) in your source code.  The value of a macro variable is replaced in source code by prefacing the symbol with an ampersand (`&`)

Example:

```
%let x = `01JUL2020`d;  * value of macro variable is source code for a SAS date literal;
%let y = 4;

* ... Later ...;

Proc SQL;
  ...
  where claim_date = &x   /* resolve symbol in source code during code submission (running man) */
  ;
```